# Render JSON Multiple Model + Map Function

Tags: ruby, json, hash, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jquery autocomplete-categories, searching two model: users and tags.
  In the controller, is it possible to do it in one json render call? It works when I simply query one of the two, but I'd like to do both. Thanks!

My current code:

```
def search
  @users = User.order(:name).where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term].downcase}%")
  @tags = Tag.order(:name).where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term].downcase}%")

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {
      render json: {
        @tags.map { |tag| {:label => tag.name, :value => tag.name, :category => "Tags" } },
        @users.map { |user| {:label => user.name, :value => user.username, :category => "Users" } }
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you have your autocomplete setup, but you'll want to start by rendering correct json

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {
    render json: {
      tags: @tags.map { |tag| {label: tag.name, value: tag.name, category: "Tags" } },
      users: @users.map { |user| {label: user.name, value: user.username, category: "Users" } }
    }
  }
end
```

If you're building out a lot of json responses, consider using [Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) to handle the conversions for you.